# From where do we know that after 70 years old we cannot complain about the death's age

Tags: sources-mekorot, age

I heard that after 70 years old, we have only bonus years. What is the source for this?

Answer (score 5):

One vision of the average lifespan is recorded in Psalm 90:10

The days of our years because of them are seventy years, and if with increase, eighty years; but their pride is toil and pain, for it passes quickly and we fly away.

```
    ייְמֵי שְׁנוֹתֵינוּ | בָּהֶם שִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה וְאִם בִּגְבוּרֹת | שְׁמוֹנִים שָׁנָה וְרָהְבָּם עָמָל וָאָוֶן כִּי גָז חִישׁ וַנָּעֻפָה:
```